# how to set C# windows form that can able to fit into all type of window screens?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

My C# Window Form size is 1364,835.It is shown perfectly in my PC.But while running with my Laptop(small screen size),only part of my form has shown in the visible area.How can able to fit this size issue among all systems.

do i need to add verticall scroll bar to my form?

Please Guide me to get out of this issue...

Saravanan.P

Comment: scroll bars on desktop app forms are unpleasant for user. Make the form smaller or allow resizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not done much work on the windows application in that case you can think of using WPF, as WPF is more capable to handle this.

Still if you want to use Window application then make sure that your controls layout properly when their size changes.  Use the Anchor and Dock properties. You can also use TableLayoutPanel in GrowAndShrink mode, but remember you might face some flickering issues if you use TableLayoutPanel in excess.

You can check MSDN for Auto Scaling  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

useanchoring, docking and etc.

look at microsoft outlook when you resize the window it changes looking another softwares can help you

Answer (score 1):

you can set one property of form

WindowState = Maximized

just try this...